# Create image in codeigniter on the fly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create image in codeigniter as we do in simple php using GD functions. i have tried the following method in controller

```
function image(){
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
        $background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
        $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
        $line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
        imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com",
          $text_colour );
        imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
        imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );
        //$this->output->set_content_type('image/png');
         header( "Content-type: image/png" );
        imagepng( $my_img );
        imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
        imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
        imagecolordeallocate( $background );
        imagedestroy( $my_img );
        }
```

If i write this code in simple php we can see in url like http://www.domain.com/image.php
 but if i run in codeigniter like http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/image
then i am unable to get image.

i have searched all around but unable to find how to create image in codeigniter . i have also found that the captcha helper create the image in same way.

Comment: This is actually working just fine. What is going wrong in there?

Comment: if call this only image is not create..

Comment: Explain what do you want to do with this image, after generating it.

Comment: actually i want to create image on the fly, so i want see in url

Comment: To do what with the url?

Comment: i want to use it as the src of another. like <img src="http://route"/>

Comment: What's working already.. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned you are trying to create a url that displays the image. try this:

```
function image(){
    $my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
    $background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
    $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
    $line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
    imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com",
      $text_colour );
    imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
    imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );
    ob_start();
    imagepng( $my_img );
    $image_string = ob_get_flush();
    $imageb64 = base64_encode($image_string);
    imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
    imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
    imagecolordeallocate( $background );
    imagedestroy( $my_img );
    $url = "data:image/png;base64,".$imageb64;
    return $url;
}
```

in order to displace this image using a url, you

Comment: could you modify the above code...it would be helpful for me.

Comment: i want image data in string...ob_start() not working

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan please see further edits. I'm not sure what you want to do with the string once you get it, but I assumed you want to return it from the function image().

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan this edit is my last try. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want the function to return a string that is a url you can display for someone to click on and see the image (that's what I have written up here)? Or do you want the browser to immediately render the image? You haven't made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do typical image manipulations like watermarking, resizing, cropping, etc.
and since you are already using Code Igniter, I wanted to link you to **imagemoo**

http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/

Of course, it depends on what you want to accomplish as an output image.
for me, I find its good to create from base PNG image file and then manipulate it from there.

Comment: i dont want to manipulate image ...i just want to create a new image.

Comment: Ammar, just in case you didn't notice. you used imagepng() without filename. it won't save any file and it will dumps all into the browser screen

Comment: 1. Try to comment out header( "Content-type: image/png" );  while you are debugging 
2. close the browser you have and re-open it